# Reset Nautilus "Computer" folder list

Tags: fedora, gnome-shell, nautilus

In my setup I tend to symlink major user folders in Linux to their Windows equivalents, IE Downloads, Documents, Pictures, Videos, etc. Usually I make sure nautilus isn't running before I do it and the default list of folders under "Computer" stays the same

However my last change I forgot to do this and now the 4 folders above are filed under Bookmarks. Deleting the nautilus settings folder at `~/.conf/nautilus` doesn't fix it. Reinstalling nautilus with `yum reinstall nautilus  nautilus-extensions` doesn't fix it. I'm not sure where else to go as I don't know how nautilus is loading these folders

Does anyone have any suggestions on what to do to put the folders back under Computer?

Comment: @don_crissti Yes. There it looks cleaner and doesn't make the entire side pane scroll since there isn't an extra Bookmarks category

Answer (score 1):

I do know it is not a good practice to dig up an old post like this one, but I really needed an answer to the same problem here in 2019 and couldn't find a proper solution, until now.

Solving the problem is as simple as editing the `.config/user-dirs.dirs` file by pasting this in a terminal:

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

You will find something like:

```
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="/data/downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="/data/drive"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/data/music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/data/pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/data/videos"
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="/data/desktop"
```

Type inside the quotes the real path to the folders you desire to show again in the sidebar. For exemple: The XDG_DESKTOP_DIR= entry should be equal to your desktop folder (probably "$HOME/Desktop"). If it is missing, just type it in and save the file. Reboot and it should be back.

Found the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/745258/806380, by https://askubuntu.com/users/511925/user3556519.